# What is the right way to update PROJECTION fields in GSI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have chose `ProjectionType: INCLUDE` as projection type for one of my `GSI` in dynamodb table. And I listed a few `NonKeyAttributes`. But I found there is no way for me to update the `NonKeyAttributes`. I wonder what is the suggested way to update it. I can only find two options:

1. Create another GSI with a different name including the updated `NonKeyAttributes`. Then update my application to use the new GSI
2. Backup table data. Delete the GSI and re-create it. Then restore the data.

Both options take a long time and require a bit of work. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to backup the table data for option 2.

Simply delete the GSI and re-create it with the new projection fields.

Comment: I think you are right that `recreate` works. But it requires a certain amount of time to rebuild the index and my application doesn't work during this time period. Is there a better way to do?